# CImg - Saliency with spectral approach

Tags: c++, image-processing, cimg

I am trying to implement the spectral approach to get the saliency of an image with CImg, but I'm having trouble getting there.
This might seems like a repost from this question ([spectral residual saliency detection in C++ with CImg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548906/spectral-residual-saliency-detection-in-c-with-cimg)) but I think I got right the two mistakes from this question (atan2 and FFT arguments).

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    const char * input_file = "img/pic.png";

    CImg<float> input = CImg<float>(input_file);
    const CImg<float> mask(3,3,1,1,1.0f/9.0f);

    resize_fft(input); // Resize for fft
    CImg<float> gray = any2gray(input); // to single channel grayscale

    CImgList<float> fft = gray.get_FFT();

    CImg<float> amp = (fft[0].get_pow(2) + fft[1].get_pow(2)).get_sqrt();
    CImg<float> amp_log = (amp + 1.0f).get_log().get_normalize(0, 255);

    CImg<float> phase = fft[1].get_atan2(fft[0]);
    CImg<float> residual = amp_log - amp_log.get_convolve(mask);
    CImg<float> real = residual.get_exp();
    CImg<float>::FFT(real, phase, true);

    real.save("img/001.png");
    real.normalize(0, 255).save("img/002.png");

    return 1;
}
```

Both save pictures 001 and 002 end up being noise-like picture, like still in the frequency space.
I don't what's something wrong with what I'm doing, if yuo guys can help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, It is obvious that you forget to smooth `real` with Gaussian filter.

Secondly, the line `CImg<float>::FFT(real, phase, true);` is suspectable. I don't know about `CImg` library but I can understand what you are expressing. When you do `inverse fft`, I think that both the real part and the imaginary part are wrong. The formulae in the paper are kind of misleading, reading [the matlab code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38512-visual-scanpaths-via-constrained-levy-exploration-of-a-saliency-landscape/content/CLE/saltool/SpectralR/SpectralResidualSaliency.m) is clearer.
If you are familiar with complex number, you will find that getting variable `phase` is not necessary here.
The pseudo code replacing the line are here:

```
fft[0] = fft[0] ./ amp .* residual;
fft[1] = fft[1] ./ amp .* residual;
//Inverse Fourier Transform
CImg<float>::FFT(fft[0], fft[1], true);
real = fft[0].get_pow(2) + fft[1].get_pow(2);
real.get_convolve(Gaussian filter with sigma = 8)
```

All the operators with left dot mean element-wise operation.